# How to reduce WSUS disk usage?

Tags: wsus

My WSUS installation is now using 100 Gb of disk.

Is there a way to reduce this usage? How can I, say, delete updates included in Service Packs?

Comment: If the very good advice from David times out, check this link:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/7b12f8b2-d0e6-4f63-a98a-019356183c29/getting-past-wsus-cleanup-wizard-time-out-removing-unnecessary-updates?forum=winserverwsus#7b12f8b2-d0e6-4f63-a98a-019356183c29

Answer (score 9):

You can go to Options > Server Cleanup Wizard, in the WSUS window, and clean up unused updates and update revisions, computers not contacting the server, uneeded update files, expired updates, and superseded updates. I do this approx. once a week, sometimes a little less frequently.

[image: WSUS Server Cleanup Wizard]

Comment: This dialog never finishes. I let it run for several days and the cleaning never came to end.

Comment: Great walk-through... Saved me about 70% of wasted space by WSUS.
WSUS should handle the superseded files automatically, this is a huge miss by Microsoft again... This company is getting consistently worse each year: product evolution, quality, support, design, cloud obsessed...
Thank you for taking the time to share this article.

Answer (score 1):

I have found another quite effective approach.

Go `All Updates` folder, and set:

- `Approved` on Approval field
- `Any` on status field

Then right click on column titles and check `Supersencence`. A new column 2 will appear. Use it to sort all your approved items.

Select all superseded items (they are grouped by 2 different icons), and decline them.

Then go in `Options`->`Server cleanup wizard` and set only `Unneeded update files`

Run it.

*NOTE: This 'brutal' approach saved a choking server by reducing the disk* usage (about 50%).